# How to have a link in an image?

Tags: javascript

Basically what I'm doing here is moving through divs/questions with a next arrow. When all the questions are done. The next arrow disappears and an identical arrow comes up with a link in it. Currently it works in terms of scrolling through the questions and the arrows disappearing etc. However the link to Google does not work.

```
var actual = 0; // select by default the first question


$(document).ready(function() {


var number_of_question = $('.question').length; // get number of questions
$('#link').hide();
$('.question:gt(' + actual + ')').hide(); // Hide unselect questions



$('#nextQ').click(function() {

    if (actual < number_of_question - 1) {
        changeQuestion(actual + 1); // display select question
    }

    if (actual === number_of_question - 1){
    $('#previousQ').hide();
    $('#nextQ').hide();
    $('#digit').hide();
    $('#ledgend').hide();
    $('#question_number').hide();
    $('#link').show();
    $('#link').html('<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>');
    document.getElementById("finished").style.backgroundColor="black";
    }

});
$('#previousQ').click(function() {
    if (actual) {
        changeQuestion(actual - 1); // display select question
    }
});
});

function changeQuestion(newQuestion) {

$('.question:eq(' + actual + ')').hide(); // hide current  question
$('.question:eq(' + newQuestion + ')').show(); // show new question
actual = newQuestion; // memorize actual selection
$('#question_number').html(actual);
}
```

HTML

```
<input class="left_arrow1" id="link" type="image" src="images/right_arrow.png">
<input class="left_arrow" type="image" src="images/right_arrow.png" id="nextQ">
<input class="right_arrow" type="image" src="images/left_arrow.png" id="previousQ">
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: What is the `#link` element – can you post some HTML

Comment: Is it even getting into the second if statement? You should test with a console.log to see what the `actual` value is set to at the beginning of the $('#nextQ').click(function() {}) function.

Comment: HTML is printed above. It appears to be working except for the link to google.

Answer (score 0):

Because `#link` is an image, you can't put anything inside it. You'll need to wrap the `<a>` around it. Good thing jQuery has that!

```
$('#link').wrap('<a href="http://www.google.com">');
```